# dual boot problem. error: unknown command 'drivemap'. error: invalid EFI file path

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. But when selecting Windows to boot I get following error: error: unknown command 'drivemap' error: invalid EFI filepath

I ran boot-repair twice. The output can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9648776

Hope you can help me

Comment: This actually did not work for me. The answer in the below link is what worked for me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/279275/dual-boot-problem-windows-8-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can try **Simply start Ubuntu**

1. Go to Terminal
2. Use the below mentioned commands,

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   It will ask for the password,enter your password.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   boot-repair &
   ```

   enter your password again.
3. Once the installation gets completed, the Boot Repair utility will launch and do a quick scan. Automatically will show you the EFI detected message. **Hit OK**
4. After this, Click the Recommended repair (repairs most frequent problems) option. Once done with that.
5. Restart your computer